# kudan 1.4.1 purchased key does not work

Tags: kudan

I have purchased Kudan license key past year, but after upgrading Kudan Ar to version 1.4.1 my purchased key does not work, and seems to be not valid. 
On the official web site i have not found any info of how to change the existing format key to the bundle_id/[base64 encoded key.

if I go to the [kudan keys web page](http://kudan.eu/keys) it tells me the info about my purchased key, but in the old format style.

while using the markerless kudan i can see key errors in log, same as if i change the bundle_id on prev version. 
can't reach kudan team in their portal or FB.
Any help on the topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should contact Kudan through their support portal. You can find a link for it on https://www.kudan.eu/support/

Comment: Already did. No response from yesterdays morning. What is their average time? They were responding within couple of hours in the past

Comment: Tnx for the response on the portal. Looking forwards, to build my app.